# C: close(2) after fork()?

Tags: c, fork

Quick question, hoping someone can verify. After a fork, if you call `close(2)` in the parent, stderr in the child is unaffected. However, if you call `close(2)` in the child, stderr in the parent is closed. Does that seem right? I tested this in FreeBSD and it seems to be the case, but I'm not sure why. I would expect that either they both don't affect each other or they do, but not this.

Any insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a fork, every open file descriptor in the parent gets dup'ed, so any close *after* the fork won't affect either the parent or the child.

Unless, you're doing it not properly (i.e. not checking the output of the `fork()` system call).

Comment: right. most probably you have a different bug makes you think that parent `stderr` is closed.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just misread the output in my test. I just ran it again and it does not appear to be happening. I thought it didn't make sense!